# Map generic type that receives constructor parameters with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

My questions is related to a specific scenario that I don't know how to handle it.
I have a mapper registered between Application and ApplicationModel and vice verse.
Now I am calling a method that returns an IPagedList

**GetApplications Method:**

```
IPagedList<Application> GetApplications()
{
   IQueryable items = context.Applications...
   return new PagedList<Application>(items, 1, 10);
}
```

And this is where I get my error because PagedList doesn't have a default constructor when it tries to make the mapping.

```
IPagedList<Application> applications = GetApplications();         
var toRet = Mapper.Map<IPagedList<ApplicationModel>>(applications); //here I get the error
```

I tried to figure out how this is done with ConstructUsing but honestly I need help to structure the call correctly if that is the correct path

Bellow are the interface and the implementation of IPagedList

**Interface:**

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
{
    int CurrentPage { get; }
    int TotalPages { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
    int TotalCount { get; }
    bool HasPrevious { get; }
    bool HasNext { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
{
    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        Items = items;
        TotalCount = count;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        CurrentPage = pageNumber;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        AddRange(Items);
    }

    public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize) : this(source.AsEnumerable(), source.Count(), pageNumber, pageSize)
    {

    }

    public int CurrentPage { get; }
    public int TotalPages { get; }
    public int PageSize { get; }
    public int TotalCount { get; }
    public bool HasPrevious => CurrentPage > 1;
    public bool HasNext => CurrentPage < TotalPages;
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProjectTo<ApplicationModel>()` or map the `IQueryable<Applications>` to `List<ApplicationModels>`, then throw it into PagedList's constructor and won't deal with the default constructor issue in AutoMapper.

ProjectTo Example:

`var toRet = new PagedList<ApplicationModel>(context.Applications...ProjectTo<ApplicationModel>(), 1, 10);`

Comment: is this what you mean? CreateMap(typeof(IPagedList<>), typeof(PagedList<>)).ConstructProjectionUsing(src => new PagedList....

Comment: I can't map it on that way because the models and the entities are handle in different layers. So in my case I am calling GetApplications from a DAL then on my Business Layer I am mapping the result to the corresponding model, but I am not returning never an IQueryable to the Business Layer